# Pass custom data from a container to a VM at creation time

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'd like to pass custom data which is a shell script in BLOB storage. Can I somehow specify the URI of the script, and make the VM execute it on start?

How do I specify the information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/extensions-customscript) in the template [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-linux-extensions/tree/master/CustomScript) on GitHub.

Public configuration

```
{
  "fileUris": ["http://MyAccount.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/MyShellScript.sh"],
  "commandToExecute": " sh MyShellScript.sh"
}
```

Protected configuration

```
{
  "storageAccountName": "MyAccount",
  "storageAccountKey": "Mykey"
}
```

Using template, following example works for Linux VM:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
  "name": "<extension-deployment-name>",
  "apiVersion": "<api-version>",
  "location": "<location>",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', <vm-name>)]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "publisher": "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions",
    "type": "CustomScriptForLinux",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "1.5",
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
    "settings": {
      "fileUris": [
        "<url>"
      ],
      "commandToExecute": "<command>"
    },
    "protectedSettings": {
      "storageAccountName": "<storage-account-name>",
      "storageAccountKey": "<storage-account-key>"
    }
  }
}
```

Update:

If you want to use Python SDK to do this, see following example.

```
##Using Azure Custom Script to execute script inside VM
GROUP_NAME = 'shuicli'
vmname = 'shui'
ext_type_name = 'CustomScriptForLinux'
ext_name = 'shuitest'
params_create = {
    'location': 'eastus',
    'publisher': 'Microsoft.OSTCExtensions',
    'virtual_machine_extension_type': ext_type_name,
    'type_handler_version': '1.0',
    'auto_upgrade_minor_version': True,
    'settings': {
        'fileUris': ["https://shuilinuxdiag336.blob.core.windows.net/customscriptfiles/test.sh"],
        'commandToExecute': 'sh test.sh'
    }, 
    'protected_settings' : {
        'storageAccountName': 'shuilinuxdiag336',
        'storageAccountKey': '<your storage account key>'
    },
}
ext_poller = compute_client.virtual_machine_extensions.create_or_update(
    GROUP_NAME,
    vmname,
    ext_name,
    params_create,
)
ext = ext_poller.result()
```

Comment: Is there an example anywhere, where the fileURI and commandToExecute have actually been used?

I'm not sure of where the key provided should be placed in the template over  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines).

Comment: @VarunVembar See this [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-customscript-extension-azure-storage-on-ubuntu/azuredeploy.json).

Comment: If you use Visual Studio, you could add a new resource easily. https://imgur.com/a/YQsHx

Comment: I was not able to merge the two together. I'm unsure of how the 'properties' key of the JSON fits in the VM template

Comment: @VarunVembar Could you share your currently template?  You just need this [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-customscript-extension-azure-storage-on-ubuntu) and deploy it to Azure. https://imgur.com/a/rInmL

Comment: If you are new to Azure template, you could check this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates) firstly. This [template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines) you provided is only a part resources in `"resources":[]`, you only need resources `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions` at the end of it.

Comment: This is the template

Comment: Sorry here it is 

https://pastebin.com/cxtJdJCy

I'm creating the VM using the python SDK. Can't figure out where to pass the property in the JSON

Comment: @VarunVembar You need create your VM fristly, then execute custom script extension. You could check this [python SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.compute.v2017_12_01.operations.virtualmachineextensionsoperations?view=azure-python).

Comment: So can't I execute the custom script extension at the time of creating the VM?

Do I need to have an already existing VM in place?

And is this link(https://pastebin.com/AVLNWLDi) the right way to pass the property in the JSON?

Comment: No, you could. Azure custom script extension is a independent resource. Only VM is created and started, then you could execute the script.

Comment: Also, Azure does not support the usage of your example. You need create VM firstly then create custom script extension to execute your script.

Comment: And is the template I'm using accurate? Because I wasn't able to get anything to execute

Comment: I think you need remove `'properties':
        {
            'settings':
            {
                'fileURIs':
                [
                    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/weavermonkey/test-azure-shell/master/test_python_script.py'
                ],
                'commandToExecute':'python test_python_script.py'
            }
        }`. Because custom script is not a properties for a VM.

Comment: Nic, IP these are VM's properties, VM extension is a independent resource.

Comment: Create a VM with python, see this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/virtualmachines?view=azure-python

Comment: I've already created the VM. Could you please tell me how to use this (https://github.com/Azure/custom-script-extension-linux) in the python SDK? Or any method at all to execute a command in a VM programatically?

Comment: Check this [sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.compute.v2017_12_01.operations.virtualmachineextensionsoperations?view=azure-python). The [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.compute.v2017_12_01.operations.virtualmachineextensionsoperations?view=azure-python) you could check.

Comment: I test this [example](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Walter-Shui/ab5f72e33aac22f2dae93fbafcd67c6c/raw/4bd73c96b2cae01d8389428f63d62ab77f0a384e/script_extension.py) in my lab. But I meet one issue, maybe you could check.

Comment: shall I go ahead and ask a new question?

Comment: I suggest you could ask a new question about how to use python to create Custom Script extension. Sorry, I am not very good at Python.

Comment: @VarunVembar I update my answer, I used a wrong method. Now, I solve it, I could use this example to create custom script extension.